# Android not make GET request after app closing from Service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, android-volley

First of all sorry if such sort of question is already asked before.

I want to make a app which make a `GET request` or Simply `Open A URL` to tell server that app is closed now, ***no output is needed just load URL.***

What I already tried:

1. I used `Volley` but unfortunately its not a solution in this  case.
2. I also tried to make `AsyncTask` but seriously friend its weird its also not working

Only what's work is a simple line of code:

```
URL url = new URL("URL HERE"); 
InputStream stream = url.openStream();
```

but cause `NetworkException`. I just want to Execute a URL from Service after app closing.

> Sample Codes Will Appreciate

**THanks In Advance**

***Update Section***

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {

    public int isExecuted = 0;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("rrLOG", "Service Started");
        checkClosing();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.e("rrLOG", "Service Stopped");
        updateServer(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("rrLOG", "Service Destroyed");
        updateServer(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
        stopSelf();
    }

    public void checkClosing(){

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Helper.isAppRunning(Service.this, getPackageName())) {
                    Log.i("rrLOG", "App Is Running");
                } else {
                    Log.i("rrLOG", "App Is Not Running");
                    updateServer(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 500);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second

    }

    static class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    responseString = out.toString();
                    out.close();
                } else{
                    //Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //TODO Handle problems..
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //TODO Handle problems..
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Do anything with response..
        }
    }

    public void updateServer(final String urlJsonArry) {

        Log.i("rrLOG", urlJsonArry);

        new RequestTask().execute(urlJsonArry);

    }


}
```

***UPDATE2 Section***

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {

    public int isExecuted = 0;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("rrLOG", "Service Started");
        checkClosing();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.e("rrLOG", "Service Stopped");
        updateServer(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("rrLOG", "Service Destroyed");
        updateServer(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
    }

    public void checkClosing(){

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Helper.isAppRunning(Service.this, getPackageName())) {
                    Log.i("rrLOG", "App Is Running");
                } else {
                    Log.i("rrLOG", "App Is Not Running");
                    updateServer(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 500);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second

    }

    public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.i("rrLOG", String.valueOf(isExecuted));
            URL url = null; //get URL from your uri object
            try {
                url = new URL(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                InputStream stream = url.openStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("rrLOG", String.valueOf(url));
            return String.valueOf(url);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.i("rrLOG", "onPostExecute");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }


    public void updateServer(String urlJsonArry) {

        Log.i("rrLOG", urlJsonArry);

            if(isExecuted == 0) {
                new NetworkTask().execute();
                isExecuted = 1;
            }

    }


}
```

Comment: Try using Intentservice or JobScheduler

Comment: any Sample code related with this suggestion?

Comment: Can you post your service code

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html

Comment: Yes of course, check in update section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, every network request is to be made on worker thread. That thread is different to UI thread. You have to make network request in background via `AsyncTask`. Example below:

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    public Void doInBackground() {
        // Here you can make network request 
    }
}
```

Now you can make this request inside a Service, so even if your activity is killed the network request will go through.

Kindly ensure you have internet permissions in Manifest.

**Edit:**

I checked the attached code in question, you are trying to stop the service at the same time when you have triggered a network request. If you do so, your network request won't be even completed before it is killed by the system.

You can kill service once your network request is completed, i.e. inside `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Ok Bro, Seems Its My Mistake.. I haven't make changes I gonna make change let's see what happen

Comment: What I note is that onPostExecute Is Not Called I check via Log.i

Comment: check UPDATE2 Section

Comment: also is there any specific need , you wan't to call your updateServer method via a Timer ?

Comment: I just want to send response to server accurately, I dont want that app mis a single shot

Comment: @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.e("rrLOG", "Service Stopped");
        updateServer(UPDATE_OFFLINE);
    } .. is this method getting called when you press a back key in your device  ?

Comment: Its actually about how many users online, if you have any better suggestion let me know please

Comment: onTaskRemoved() called when app is closed but wait  its not needed

Comment: I gonna remove this

Comment: if you just want to track online users .. so while coming out of activity when back key is pressed .. you can override a method called onBackPressed .. and from that method you can trigger and intent service to post data to updated

Comment: Sorry I can't remove it its only method called after app closing

Comment: ok .. i am not saying to remove any method..wait lets find some other soln

Comment: No brother, actually its unsave as some users close app from recent task list that's why their status will be inaccurate

Comment: ok .. is you updateServer method is getting called from onTaskRemoved as you press back key ?

Comment: yes actually this method called from both ways, onBackPRess and also when app is closed from recent task list

Comment: any solution you got??

Answer (score 0):

public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        SessionManager manager=new SessionManager ();
        Log.i("rrLOG", String.valueOf(isExecuted));
        URL url = null; //get URL from your uri object
        try {
            url = new URL(paste your url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        try {
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("rrLOG", String.valueOf(url));
        return String.valueOf(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("rrLOG", "onPostExecute");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        stopSelf();
    }
}


public void updateServer(String url) {

    Log.i("rrLOG", urlJsonArry);

    if(isExecuted == 0) {
        new NetworkTask().execute();
        isExecuted = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: use this method for api trigger and volley is not work in Service method so replace this